# Late Night Ground Transportation from El Calafate to Puerto Natales / Torres del Paine

Tags: transportation, argentina, night-transport, patagonia

A few friends and I were hoping to visit Patagonia this January.

We will be flying in to El Calafate at 6:30 PM on a Monday, and hoping to get to Torres del Paine as quickly as possible.

I'm wondering if there is an overnight bus service from El Calafate to Puerto Natales or, even better, Torres del Paine.

I've read that a lot of people arrange for private ground transportation (i.e. a private coach hire). If so, what are the companies and how are people making these bookings?

Comment: @pnuts Yeap the car rental ends up costing us over $600 + gas so I'm trying to get a price point for the comparison.

Comment: I disagree. I'm not looking for a shopping recommendation. I'm asking whether there is a ground transportation option to get from one city to a national park. The question is specific / transportation related and seems to be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In El Calafate, you will find lots and lots of small travel agencies that offer tours to Torres del Paine. They're quite flexible at organizing whatever you want to do at a reasonable price. Of course in your case, you'll want to book in advance. So just search for "travel agency el calafate" and write some emails.